# Maintaining reactjs element state when removing it from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm building an website using ReactJS. I have a div in place, and its content is decided based on the state of a radio button (it changes the value of media):

```
<div className="card_container">
     { this.state.media=="image" ? <MediaCard /> : <TextCard /> }
</div>
```

Both the elements rendered inside card_container have a text field, and I'd like for their content not to be discarded when switching between states. For example, if in the text area inside MediaCard I type "foo", switch to TextCard and then back to MediaCard, then I lose the text I have entered in the text area.

How can I maintain the original MediaCard element and just re-render the original with the text and all of its props and state?

**EDIT:** At the moment, I have solved this by bubbling up the properties of the contained elements, and then pass them as props when I re-render those elements. It's an ugly solution, though, and I'd rather find a better one...

Comment: Just a thought: perhaps try cloning the object in componentWillUnmount(), to capture its properties?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but even when I try to add a reference to that element (for example - if on MediaCard's parent I add: this.state.MC = <MediaCard /> and then render this.state.MC, it still creates a brand new element

Comment: I'd bubble the state to the parent. But, if that seems "ugly" to you, why not just use CSS to hide/show the `Card` that is active? That way it won't be destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're switching between components at render-time, then `react` can't tell that the text field should be kept or not when re-rendering, so it recreates it along with the parent component. A solution to this problem would be to have a single `Card` component that behaves upon a `type` parameter, instead of two:

```
<div className="card_container">
     {<Card type={this.state.media} />}
</div>
```

this way `react` will be able detect that the text field can be preserved.

**Edit.** If your component hierarchy needs two separate components, you can render both, and have only one visible at a time:

```
var hasMedia = this.state.media == "image";

<div className="card_container">
    <MediaCard  visible={hasMedia}/>
    <TextCard  visible={!hasMedia}/>
</div>
```

Each component will keep it's state, and you'll have only one present on the screen at a time

Comment: I'm using 2 cards because they look and behave completely different from one another. Even if I pass the value of media as a property, I would still need to render 2 different react elements based on media, and this situation will repeat itself...

Comment: That makes sense, I suspected this is the reason why you have two components; unfortunately this affects the optimisations made by react when re-rendering the components, as every time it renders the parent component it creates a brand new MediaCard/TextCard.

Comment: You can try passing the text as a property to the card component, and have the cards call a delegate method from the parent when they get unmounted, however it's kinda ugly and adds tight-coupling between your components.

Comment: @Luoruize: I updated my answer and added another possible solution

Comment: Thanks @Cristik! I was thinking about doing the same thing. I got another recommendation to use Flux and just pass the data model to the component each time it renders. While more elegant, your solution fits me better because I have to display images in these components and I would hate for them to reload every time.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you think, your approach is like a tabbed-view but without a tab control, as you are changing between views based on a selection, so it would make sense to have all views rendered, but only one visible.